# gluLookAt in openGL never changes the view

Tags: c, opengl, graphics

I have been googling this for awhile and haven't been able to fix my code.  I am just trying to get gluLookAt() to look at a certain point on a surface.

I have an init() function that should set the starting point to look at when the program runs, but it never changes the view.

Here is my init():

```
void init(void){
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(65.0,1.0,1.0,100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,6.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing either the eye or center position? Also, are you sure your rendering code works?

Comment: I am able to display a bezier surface patch on the screen.  Right now I am just trying to get it to look at an initial point on the surface of the patch by using gluLookAt().  For some reason no matter what I put inside of gluLookAt the patch always renders the same.

Comment: If nothing else, you could try using `glTranslatef` and `glRotatef` to manually change the view matrix, see if that makes a difference. Also, make sure `glLoadIdentity` isn't getting called somewhere in your render loop.

Comment: I thought I had commented out glLoadIdentity but had one in my render loop argh.  Thanks.